# How do I not allow duplicates to be added into an Binary Search Tree?

Tags: java, duplicates, binary-search-tree

I've been trying to figure out how to edit my given code to where it will not allow an element into my binary tree if it already exists.  My hints were to modify two different classes outside of the tester to do so.

My first class is:

```
public void addNode(Node <T> newNode){
        Comparable<T> tempElement = (Comparable<T>) newNode.element;

        int comp = tempElement.compareTo(element);
          if (comp < 0)
          {  
             if (left == null) 
                 {left = newNode;}
             else 
                 {left.addNode(newNode);}
          }
          else
          {  
             if (right == null) 
                 {right = newNode;}
             else 
                 {right.addNode(newNode);}

          }
    }
```

And the second is:

```
public void add(T obj) // add root first
    {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(obj);
        if (root == null) {
            root = newNode;
        } else {
            root.addNode(newNode);
        }
        count++;

    }
```

If anyone could help me out that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `if (comp == 0)`; or change the `else` to `else if (comp > 0)`.

Comment: I'm suspicious about the cast `(Comparable<T>)`. If you've declared `element` as `T element;` and you've bounded `T` via `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, you wouldn't need to cast explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using instances of `Comparable` which are consistent with equals; that is:

```
a.compareTo(b) == 0  iff  a.equals(b)
```

Then you can eliminate duplicates simply by checking for the case that:

```
a.compareTo(b) == 0
```

The easiest way to achieve this in your current code is simply to check the value of `comp`:

```
if (comp < 0)
{
  // Insert to the left, as you currently do.
}
else if (comp > 0)
{
  // Insert to the right, as you currently do.
}
else
{
  // Handle the duplicate: maybe do nothing, maybe throw an exception etc.
  // If you want to do nothing, you don't need the else block at all.
}
```

---

To solve the second half of the problem, change your `addNode` method to return a `boolean`, where `true` means the node was added, and `false` that it wasn't.

Then:

```
Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(obj);
if (root == null) {
  root = newNode;
  count++;  // "added" unconditionally.
} else {
  if (root.addNode(newNode)) count++;  // Only increment if it was really added.
}
```

Comment: I was about to post this exact answer, but you beat me to it. This is correct. +1

Comment: Thank you! This helped the first half of my problem. Haha now I need to alter the "count" code to where if a duplicate was added on the tester but not to the tree, the count should stay the same rather than increase.  For example this should return 6 for the count instead of 8: myBST.add(10);
  myBST.add(7);
  myBST.add(15);
  myBST.add(3);
  myBST.add(3);
  myBST.add(9);
  myBST.add(8);
  myBST.add(8);
  return myBST;

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help, I'm still not 100% finished and I'm still having snags but I don't want you to do my work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your items into a Set, as sets only allow one instance of items that are equal.

```
Set items=new HashSet();
```

Comment: OP is implementing a BST. Putting things into a `Set` kinda defeats the point.